# Not covering batch execute method querying CampaignMember

Tags: batch, code-coverage, campaign-member

AccountActivityUpdateBatch class execute method is not covering the for loop.

Here is my test class.

```
@istest
public class AccountActivityUpdateBatchTest {
    @testSetup static void setup() {
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = 'TestAccount';
        Insert acc; 

        Contact contact  = new Contact();        
        contact.FirstName = 'Test';        
        contact.LastName = 'Contact';
        contact.AccountId = acc.Id;
        Insert contact;

        Campaign c = new Campaign();
        c.Name = 'TESTCAMPAIGN';
        c.isactive = true;
        c.status = 'In Progress'; 
        c.StartDate = Date.today().addDays(2);
        c.EndDate = Date.today().addDays(3);
        Insert c;

        CampaignMember cm = new CampaignMember();
        cm.CampaignId = c.Id;
        cm.ContactId = contact.Id;
        cm.Status = 'Accepted';
        insert cm;
    }

    static testmethod void testMethod1() {
        Test.startTest();
        Database.executeBatch(new AccountActivityUpdateBatch());
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Batch class:

```
global class AccountActivityUpdateBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

/*********************************** Start method *******************************************/
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator('****Query****');
}

/********************************** Execute method ******************************************/
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> scope){

    Map<Id, List<CampaignMember>> campaignsMap = new Map<Id, List<CampaignMember>>();
    //Not entering for loop
    for (CampaignMember cm : [SELECT Id, CampaignId, Campaign.Name, Campaign.StartDate, Contact.AccountId 
                              FROM CampaignMember ]) {
        //******Logic here*******
    }
}

/*********************************** Finish method *******************************************/
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){

}
}
```

Comment: What is the query you are passing on in the `start` method ?

Comment: `Start` method queries all accounts which I need to update.

Comment: So you've confirmed that execution *does* enter the `execute()` method, but does not enter the loop? Are there filters on that `CampaignMember` query that you've elided? Right now it doesn't make sense in a batch context.

Comment: @DavidReed Yes there are filters in where conditions. If I removed those filters also its not entering to for loop.

Comment: this batch execute looks odd -- you are passing in Accounts but then querying ALL CampaignMembers -- you may blow up Limits if you have large campaign member sets.

Comment: @cropredy Before querying campaignmembers I fetch contacts of all accounts in scope. Then I use those contactIds to check campaignmembers. I haven't included all my logic here.